# Как сменить свойство объекта при клонировании?

Tags: ооп, php

```
class Foo{
    public $hoom=100;
    private $ty='ee';
    public $re=8;
    function __clone(){
        $this->boggota=9;
        unset($this->hoom);
        }
    }
    $obj=new Foo;
    $obj2=clone $obj;
    print_r($obj2);
    print_r($obj);
```

Вот есть метод __clone().Можно менять свойства в клонированном объекте.А как сменить свойства в объекте исходном и в самом классе каждый раз при клонировании(например сменить статическое свойство и не только)?

Answer (score 1):

Статическое свойство - это некая фиксированная область в оперативной памяти (если речь идет о статических полях класса). Т.е это поле, по сути, никак не зависит от объектов класса,  доступ к нему осуществляется через имя класса. Исходя из этого, попробуйте сами решить свою проблему)

Comment: а доступ к исходному объекту получить можно?